# What is the difference between "find" and "determine" as an instruction in mathematics?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice

I want to write a question in Math. as below but I don't know the difference between them:

> **Determine** the solution of the differential equation?

or

> **Find** the solution of the differential equation?

Comment: Please take a look at our [Details, Please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) post, particularly the part that says "Show your research." That will give you a better idea of how to ask questions that won't get closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Determine* means to evaluate evidence and come to a conclusion or judgement, or to gather information about a fact or state of something.

*Find* can mean this (especially in a legal context), but *find* can also mean simply "to search for the location of" - and *determine* won't ever mean that.

But it's possible to "determine" the state or location of things, but you do need to specify the attribute you are determining, whereas with *find X* it's implied you are trying to determine *where X* is located.

A contrived example to illustrate:

> I lost my keys.  I can't find them.  (*Find* implies "where")
>
> I lost my keys.  I can't determine them.  (Wrong - sounds like there is a second object and you can't tell whether or not it's keys - and not necessarily your keys)
>
> I lost my keys.  I can't determine the location of them.  (We specify "location" as an attribute we want to discover, so this is OK, but a little over wordy)

Answer (score 5):

In maths both work. You'll often see many sentences involving those words.

> » ***Determine/find*** all the continuous functions that satisfy...
>   » ***Determine/find*** the nilpotent matrix which commutes...
>   » ***Determine/find*** the value of the following integral and...

They naturally work with any math sentence.
In exams or any kind of evaluation, both words are prefered.

Comment: Obligatory: [Find X](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_xMkGYt0dOw8/S_LhFVn3pYI/AAAAAAAAAB4/8HZ48rcMCB8/s320/FaceExamFrustration-find_X.gif)